# node-debug, can't save file changes

Tags: node.js, node-red, node-debugger

I start 'node-debug' to debugging my node-red nodes.

```
$ sudo node-debug --web-host=127.0.0.1  --save-live-edit=true /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js
```

The debugger works fine but i can't save file changes.
I get a error mesage like this...

```
Saving files is not enabled in hosted mode. Please inspect using chrome://inspect
```

I can't find setting for the hosted mode?
Is there an alternative way to change this?

Comment: resolve, it only works if you stop your Source with a breakpoint

Comment: In case @zombinary 's comment was not clear, it means that you can't just edit and save the code without having reached a breakpoint first. Add a breakpoint, reload the app so the code breaks there and then you can edit & save. Only then will the change get reflected at filesystem level. Tried with node v0.12.4 and node inspector v0.10.1

Comment: @ThalisK. thanks you descripte it better

Answer (score 0):

Use parameter `--save-live-edit` first and witout `=true`, like:

```
sudo node-debug --save-live-edit --web-host=127.0.0.1 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js
```